# Importing Inkscape code

Tags: errors, inkscape

I'm not able to import a Inkscape (Version 1.3) .pdf_tex file in my Latex document. I use OS Ventura. Is there anyone who can help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{inkscape/inkscape.pdf_tex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{175pt}
\input{inkscape/inkscape.pdf_tex}
\caption{Eine Inkscape-Grafik}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can't do anything without knowing your inkscape-pdf. // Try renaming the file into: inkscape.pdf ...

Comment: Thank's for answering so quickly! I constantly get this error code and I don't know how to solve it. 
56
Package pdftex.def Error: File `Inkscape.pdf' not found: using draft setting.


See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56 ...s[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Inkscape.pdf}}
                                                  %
56LaTeX Warning: File `Inkscape.pdf' not found on input line 56.

Comment: Doesn't Inkscape export `pstricks` code? In which case you need to add `\usepackage{pstricks}` and compile with `latex+dvips` or `lualatex`.

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, but what do you mean exactly? :)

Comment: pdf_tex may not be a file tension, which Latex deals with. Just a speculation. Easy to check, if you rename the file …

Comment: @MS-SPO Do you use Inkscape? Its standard export is a file with a `.tex` extension.

Comment: Yes, I use Inkscape, but I am a totally beginner. :) I just renamed the file and it still dosn't work. LaTeX Error: File `IMG/draft.pdf_tex' not found.

Comment: @AlanMunn, no, not really. So, is it a ,pdf, a .tex or some other format saved? I assumed from the description: pdf

Comment: Given your other question was answered, can this question be closed since it concerned the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: in Inkscape, create a new document. Export it as `mydrawing.tex`. Now create the following `.tex` document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\input{mydrawing}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` or `latex + dvips`, not `pdflatex`.  This document should work.

Comment: This works fine. \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{draft.pdf}
   
 \end{figure}
\end{document}   The .pdf_tex files don't work. Can someone help with the .pdf_tex files?

Comment: @Eins_oder_Null Yes, of course, but then you're not doing what your original question was asking.  This shows how you could in principle do what you were trying to do. It's fine to just include PDF as in the other answer, but it is possible to `\input` the generated TeX code from Inkscape, if that's what you want to do. And the `\input` approach has certain advantages over the PDF approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, which works:

- replace `\input`
- by `\includegraphics`

(I apologize for the SVG chosen: it's from an other recent request here ...)

I took some SVG from my system, saved it as .pdf and that's it.

[image: eagle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% for de Krauts ;-)
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{transparent}
%\graphicspath{{inkscape/inkscape.pdf_tex}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\def\svgwidth{175pt}
    % !!! THIS one fails !!!
    %\input{inkscapeeagle.pdf}
    
    % ~~~ while this one works ~~~~~~~
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{inkscapeeagle.pdf}
    \caption{Eine Inkscape-Grafik (Tschuldigung, hatte nix besseres \dots)}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mega, es hat funktioniert!!!! Tausend Dank! :)

Comment: Actually `*.pdf_tex` files created by Inkscape contain all text boxes which should be processed by LaTeX. By just using the PDF files exported, those text fields won't be included at all in your LaTeX document. So using `\input{myfile.pdf_tex}` is the right approach (just look into any `*.pdf_tex` file created by Inkscape). If you don't want to deal with all steps needed manually, you could give package `svg` a try.

Comment: @mrpiggi Thank's for replying. Unfortunately this one doesn't work. :( Can you help? :) documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includesvg[width=\linewidth,inkscapelatex=false]{./draft.svg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: This forks fine for me assuming, `draft.svg` is located in the same folder as your document and calling `pdflatex --shell-escape myfantasticdocument.tex`.

As a general hint, just saying "this doesn't work" is anything but a good error description. You should consider to update your original question, describe the error you are facing in a appropriate manner and append the correlating log file so that anyone who is willing to help has something to work with.