# Exporting .pdf_tex from Inkscape to LaTex

Tags: errors, inkscape

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
  \input{draft.pdf_tex}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The implementation works with pdf but not with .pdf_tex. Can someone please help? :)

Comment: don't just say it doesn't work, what error do you get?   inkscape will have exported two files, a tex and a pdf, you need both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing Inkscape code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695095/importing-inkscape-code)

Comment: @AlanMunn No, sorry. :(

Comment: The code you give is identical to the one in the other question, and you haven't responded to whether the solution I gave you there worked. So this is simply the same question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank's for replying! I did export both files. This is the error code: (Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty
' is not loaded.
\\color ... the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}
                                                  \renewcommand \color [2][]{}
l.57 ...gin{tabular}[t]{l}$Demand$\end{tabular}}}}
                                                  %

Comment: well `\usepackage{color}` would fix that

Comment: @AlanMunn. Sorry, I tried your solution and it didn't work either.

Comment: "didn't work" isn't sufficient to know what the problem is.

Comment: @AlanMunn where have I heard that before?

Comment: @AlanMunn I’m sorry, you’re absolutely right! I’m still new to the subject! :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank's implementation was successful! :)

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Color is used for the text in Inkscape, 
but the package 'color.sty ' is not loaded
```

can be fixed by adding

```
\usepackage{color}
```

Comment: Thank you! One last question. :) I expected that the font size in the LaTeX document would also change when the size of the graphic in Latex is changed, but there is no change in font size just a size change of the graphic (.pdf_tex file). Is there a way to change font size in Latex directly?

Comment: @Eins_oder_Null

If you want to change fotn size you have two ways :

1. Change globally font size, in properties of document class, for example: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`, where 10,11,12 pt -global fon size

2. Use specific font sizes types, see: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles#Putting_it_all_together